# How to view PDF Binary data in adobe reader using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am uploading and retrieving PDF attachment document in database in binary format uploading is done successfully when retrieving attachment I am getting response from the controller to jQuery but here I cannot display the binary data in PDF format

My controller code:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
            pdfDbEntities db = new pdfDbEntities ();
            var data = from i in db.EmpTables
                       where i.Empno == 12
                       select i;
            EmpTable pdf = (EmpTable)data.SingleOrDefault();
            byte[] pdfData = pdf.Empattch;
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(pdfData);
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Content = new StreamContent(ms);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application / pdf");
            return  response;  
}
```

jQuery code:

```
$("#btnShow").click(function () {
                var options = {};
                options.url = "/api/Pdf";
                options.type = "GET";
                options.dataType = false;
                options.contentType = false;
                options.success = function (retData) {
                    $("body").append("<iframe src='" + retData + "' style='' ></iframe>")
                    window.open(retData);

                };
                options.error = function (x,y,z) {
                    debugger
                    alert(err.statusText);
                };
                $.ajax(options);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your iframe src to the URL. You are passing it actual data, It needs header information as well, which is done between the browser and server, in order to render correctly.

I don't know asp, but you be using something like :

```
   $("body").append("<iframe src='" + options.url + "' style='' ></iframe>")
```

Comment: Ihave already try like this also:$("body").append("<iframe src='" + retData.url + "' style='' ></iframe>")it displaying none.

Comment: depends what retData is. It must be a url, in the form http://www.domainname.com/api/somefile.pdf